# How to add custom typings to this template?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, tsconfig, tsc

I am using a [template](https://github.com/bersling/typescript-library-starter) to create a NPM package with TypeScript support. It works ok but I can't wonder how to add my custom typings. I tried with many different approaches (like creating a `typings/` directory with `index.d.ts` file inside) but no success. I asked in an [issue](https://github.com/bersling/typescript-library-starter/issues/5) but seems there is no activity and I am sure there must be a way to achieve this!

If you download the template and run it, you can check it works. But please, correct me if I am wrong: with the current `tsconfig.json`, `tsc` automatically infers the typings and put them in `dist/index.d.ts`. But how if I want to add my custom typings?

Let's say, I want to make available to any customer of my library a `Dog` type. Then, in `typings/index.d.ts` (outside `src` dir) I put:

```
declare module "hwrld" {
    export interface Dog {
        name: string;
        breed: string;
        age: number;
    }
}
```

But when I build with `tsc` the custom type doesn't get compiled in the `dist/` directory. I suppose that's why testing the example-consumer throws the below error: `Module '"hwrld"' has no exported member 'Dog'`.